# How to change the position of the loading wheel in the "div" element

Tags: html, position, loading, spin.js

I am using  [`spin.js`](http://spin.js.org/) to make a loading wheel appear when a user presses a button.

The only problem is that I cannot change the position where it appears.

```
//Spinner Options
var opts = {
    lines: 13, // The number of lines to draw
    length: 7, // The length of each line
    width: 4, // The line thickness
    radius: 5, // The radius of the inner circle
    corners: 1, // Corner roundness (0..1)
    rotate: 0, // The rotation offset
    color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb
    speed: 1, // Rounds per second
    trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
    shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
    hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
    className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
    zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
    top: 'auto', // Top position relative to parent in px
    left: 'auto' // Left position relative to parent in px
};
var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin();
```

Right at the end of the options, appears `top: 'auto', left:'auto'`. I have tried entering "10" or "10px". But it raises an error.

How to change the position of the loading wheel in the "div" element?